# What is the probability that a randomly chosen number N satisfying N ≡ 1 (mod 3) is prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

What is the probability that a randomly chosen number N satisfying $N ≡ 1$ mod 3 is prime?

I know that the "probability" that a randomly chosen m $\in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime is $\frac{1}{ln(m)}$

and that $N = 1 + 3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

But I'm not sure where to proceed from here

Comment: There's a version of the Prime Number Theorem for primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) tells us that the primes $\pmod n$ are "evenly distributed" between the possible  (i.e. prime to $n$) residue classes $\pmod n$,  with a sensible definition of "evenly distributed".

Comment: Usually we assume $m\in \mathbb N$ in such problems.

Comment: @Peter: I think that's a complete answer; I don't think there's much more to say about this. Perhaps you want to post that as an answer so it can be accepted and the question doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that the number is not divisible by $3$ , the chance increases by factor $1.5$.

Hence the probability is about $$\frac{1.5}{\ln()}$$ for large .